# Getting DataFrame's Column value results in 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For stream read from FileStore I'm trying to check if first column of first row value is equal to some string. Unfortunately while I access this column in any way e.g. launching .toList() on it, it throws

```
    if df["Name"].iloc[0].item() == "Bob":
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I'm calling the customProcessing function from:

```
df.writeStream\
  .format("delta")\
  .foreachBatch(customProcessing)\
[...]
```

And inside this function I'm trying to get the value, but none of the ways of getting the data works. The same error is being thrown.

```
    def customProcessing(df, epochId):
      
      if df["Name"].iloc[0].item() == "Bob":
[...]
```

Is there a possibility for reading single cols? Or it is writeStream specific and I'm unable to use conditions on that input?

Comment: @mck thanks! That works. It was weird that error message does not suggest that this iloc is not supported in this case. If you write an answer, I'll mark it as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `iloc` for spark dataframes - this is not pandas; also there is no concept of index.

If you want to get the first item you could try

```
df.select('Name').limit(1).collect()[0][0] == "Bob"
```